# delete from table with stored procedure using concat

Tags: mysql

Quick question,

using the code bellow, im able to use a sp to perform a delete  from any table, but i dont know how to use concat to delete with the where statement.

```
CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`%` PROCEDURE `fn_del_t`(in t_name varchar(50), isrv char(50))
BEGIN
set @table_name = t_name;
set @iserver = isrv;
#  not working with where.
set @sql_text = concat('delete from ',@table_name, 'where iserver =',@iserver);
# ---- not working with where 
prepare stm from @sql_text;
execute stm;
DEALLOCATE prepare stm;
END;

call fn_del_t('the_table','localhost');
```

The error im receiving is:

```
[SQL] call fn_del_t('the_table','localhost');
[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'iserver =localhost' at line 1
```

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Able to solve with:

```
CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`%` PROCEDURE `fn_del_t`(in t_name varchar(50), isrv char(50))
BEGIN
set @table_name = t_name;
set @iserver = isrv;
#
set @sql_text = concat("delete from ",@table_name," where iserver ='",@iserver,"'");
prepare stm from @sql_text;
execute stm;
DEALLOCATE prepare stm;
END
```